# How does an OS communicate with device drivers

Tags: driver, osdev

I know that an OS provides an api for a device driver to access the configuration space so that the device driver knows the memory addresses assigned to the device and can control the device. However, my question is how does an OS communicate with device drivers? For example, let's say the OS wants a document to be printed. How does it tell that it wants a document to be printed to the printers device driver and provide the driver with the text to print? Device drivers are developed by different developers, so wouldn't the drivers expect different types or formats of data from an OS. For example, printer A's driver may expect the command byte before the text data but printer B's driver may expect the text data before the command byte.

Comment: The purpose of drivers is to provide a consistent interface that hides those vendor-specific variations.  The input from the OS is in a format defined by the OS, and each driver translates that standard data format into whatever form the device understands.

Comment: IOW, the OS not only provides its own functionality via some APIs, it also defines the APIs to which drivers must conform. Consider the sqrt() function in C. The API for it is that it takes a double and returns a double and computes a square root. If you're implementing the standard C library and writing sqrt() accordingly, it will work. But if you make sqrt() take a pointer and return a struct, it definitely won't. Get the idea?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I finally understand that there is a standard interface that device drivers must conform to so that the OS can send information to the device drivers.